# Python pandas: Comparing two dataframes with different column names and returning a df that shows True if the dfs do not match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables with data, let's call them A and B. These are excel tables loaded into dataframes using pandas. They are identical in dimensions. The columns have slightly different names but they refer to the same thing. Apart from that, the values in each cell from Town A, 1 to Town C, 3 can be different. What I want to get is a matrix that returns False if these values are different and True if they are not:

| Index | Town A | Town B | Town C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nan | nan | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 11 | nan |
| 3 | nan | 3 | nan |

And for table B

| Index | Town A_U | Town B | Town C g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nan | nan | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | nan | nan |
| 3 | nan | 4 | nan |

What I am looking for is a way to compare these tables using pandas (or any other package), so when comparing the two tables I get a table that looks like the following table C:

| Index | Town A | Town B | Town C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | True | True |
| 2 | True | False | True |
| 3 | True | False | True |

The name of the header is irrelevant, it may be Town A or Town A_U, this makes no difference.

I have tried several of the ways that have been suggested by others to people that asked similar questions on here, to no avail. I tried simply replacing the header of B with that from A, but it keeps replacing the first row of data and I have now used more time on this than I would like to admit.

Does anyone know a workaround?

KR

Comment: Your question lacks *specifics*. You don't say if the two spreadsheets have the same number of rows or not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `Index` column (in your example) refers to the rows' numbers in Excel, and both spreadsheets have the same number of rows, a possible option would be to use [`isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) from [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) to consider the `NaN` values as equal :

```
comparison = np.isclose(dfa, dfb, equal_nan=True, rtol=0, atol=0)

out = pd.DataFrame(comparison, index=dfa.index, columns=dfa.columns)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   Town A  Town B  Town C
0    True    True    True
1    True   False    True
2    True   False    True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with replace missing values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to same values and rename columns by dictionary:

```
out = A.fillna('tmp').eq(B.rename(columns=dict(zip(B.columns, A.columns))).fillna('tmp'))
print (out)
       Town A  Town B  Town C
Index                        
1        True    True    True
2        True   False    True
3        True   False    True
```

Or compare by numpy array without `rename`:

```
out = A.fillna('tmp').eq(B.fillna('tmp').to_numpy())
print (out)
       Town A  Town B  Town C
Index                        
1        True    True    True
2        True   False    True
3        True   False    True
```